# Docker App Not Always Finding Serial Ports In Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, serial-port, azure-iot-edge

I am busy with an IoT type application that requires physical hardware that is connected through a serial port. We have opted to use the Azure IoT Edge architecture to deploy the application on the PC that exists on premise. This helps our DevOps cycle.

To use Azure IoT Edge requires that our application is containerized and thus exposing serial ports can be quite a challenge. The PC is 64-bit and is running Ubuntu 20.04 and does have multiple USB, serial and LAN ports that we can plug devices into.

We have followed this great [tutorial from Losant](https://www.losant.com/blog/how-to-access-serial-devices-in-docker) to set this up.

Our container creation options look like this:

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "80/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "5000"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Privileged": true,
    "Volumes": {
      "/dev": {}
    }
  }
}
```

We map the application our application's port 80 to port 5000 on the PC and we set the Volumes and Privileged tag as suggested in the tutorial link above.

The device itself is connected through USB and thus we have had to install a driver on Ubuntu 20.04 from the [FTDI website](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/).

**My question**:

In some cases our application will find the serial port (tty/USB0), but in most cases it will not. If we power cycle the PC with the device connected the application usually finds the device. How can we change the PC setup / docker setup / application setup so that it always finds the device?

Comment: Explore the following capability of IoTEdge, so that the modules are started in the specified order, this may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11 "Startup order is helpful if some modules depend on others. For example, you may want the edgeHub module to start first so that it's ready to route messages when the other modules start."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually just an unfortunate misuse of the syntax for volumes. [This docker link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerCreate) was helpful.

The resolved syntax is as follows:

```json
{
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/dev:/dev"
        ],
        "PortBindings": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostPort": "5000"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Privileged": true
    }
}
```

After resolving that everything worked as expected.

Comment: Awesome you shared the solution! Please go ahead and verify it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explore the following capability of IoTEdge, so that the modules are started in the specified order:

> Startup order is helpful if some modules depend on others. For example, you may want the edgeHub module to start first so that it's ready to route messages when the other modules start.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11